# Realm Java - how to keep the order of the items when querying for multiple ids?

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I am using Realm for android 1.2.0 and when querying for multiple ids:

```
query.in(Constants.ID, arraysOfIdsString);
```

The results are not returned in the order given in the array. Is this a realm bug? Can i preserve somehow the order of the ids with the order of the elements returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a sort order when doing the query:

`query.int(Constants.ID, arrayOfIdString).findAllSorted(Constants.ID, Sort.DESC);`

But if your list of Id's in the array is different than what is possible through sorting them either ASC or DESC, then that is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the order from the API. So i cannot re-sort it. Solved by ordering collection by ids once it is returned from Realm. Not a nice solution though...Thanks